# Pandas: Manipulating another column's values based on other column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have another basic question. So I have a dataframe like so:
cols = a,b,c,d,e which contains integers.

I want column e's value to equal 1 if columns b and c or columns a, b and c = 1.
Although d's column does not matter in this computation, it matters somewhere else so I cannot drop it.

How would I do that on pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['a']==df['b']==df['c']==1,'e']=1
```